# I am making a hangman game with JavaScript and I am very confused

Tags: javascript

I'm really new the coding, and am having a very hard time understanding. Can someone please explain to me this? My friend was helping me but I would like to understand why things are the way it is, specifically, the var index and return parts.

```
    var guessInt = 6;
    var guessStr = "You have" + guessInt + "tries left";

    function getWord() {
        var words = new Array("JAVASCRIPT", "COMPUTER", "PROGRAMMING", "OPERATOR",
            "OPERAND", "CONDITIONAL", "REPETITION", "FUNCTION", "ARRAY", "ERROR",
            "LOOP", "BOOLEAN", "STRING", "NUMBER", "DEBUG", "SWITCH", "CASE",
            "HTML", "SCRIPT", "BODY", "DOCTYPE", "RETURN", "OBJECT", "DATE", "MATH",
            "TERNARY", "WHILE", "TABLE", "INPUT", "VALUE", "CLICK", "CLASS",
            "STYLE", "BUTTON", "DOCUMENT", "TITLE", "HEAD");
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        return words[index];
    }
```

Comment: we are not here to teach you basic concepts in a language. read up about them yourself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Googling "javascript return", "javascript math.random" and "javascript math.floor" will get you started. This site is for when you're programming something and you get stuck and need specific help, not for finding someone to teach you how to program.

Comment: `index` is a variable that holds the random integer that the statement `Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)` returns based on the length of the `words` array. `return words[index]` returns (from the function) the actual word from the array using that random integer.

Comment: I know you're not here to teach me basic concept in a language, I really just needed a good site to break everything down for me. I have a textbook that isn't helping me very much, so thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.floor()`rounds a number down.
`Math.random()` generates a random float between 0 and <1 (always below 1).
`words.length` is the length of your array.

That means:

```
var words = new Array("a", "b", "c"); // length = 3
// get a random float between 0 and < 3,
// rounded down, in other words a random int between 0 and 2
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
// returns the word at that specific index in the array
return words[index];
```

So every time you call `getWord()` you will receive 1 randomly picked word from your `words` array.

Comment: OP, note, that unless you actually make a note of that word, or remove it from the array, you may get that same word returned from the function on repeated calls to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up for me.